# Can't access JSON Object no matter what i'm trying

Tags: javascript, json

So i have this JSON Structure, which i want to access:

```
data { payload: "{"state":{"reported":{"measuredata":{…
```

JSON.parse doesnt work, neither does JSON.stringify.

i only can access payload, if i go any further, i receive error or undefined:

```
data.payload // works

data.payload["state"] //undefined
data.payload.state // undefined
data.payload[0].state // undefined
data.payload[0]["state"] // undefined
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why do you have quotes around the `{` brackets?

Comment: @tipsfedora is that typo in your JSON added by you? Your { is in quotes

Comment: are check your json in json validator is this correct or not

Comment: i suspect it was probably a typo but i couldnt give an answer without knowing

Comment: please provide full json, so that we can help you in better way.

Comment: already solved guys. thanks for your efford. See Alexandru's answer.

Comment: could you please format/change the JSON sample so it matches what you have as it currently looks incorrect for JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `JSON.parse` for `payload` json string value.

```
JSON.parse(data.payload).state;
```

Comment: This is wrong, since the value of payload is not a string.

Comment: but it works. thanks alexandru.
`JSON.parse(data.payload).state.reported.measuredata` returns what i want.

Comment: Payload is apparently a string, and the question is badly formatted.

Comment: this solution shouldnt work as the sample provided isnt valid JSON

Comment: what should i do if i'm receiving this from amazon aws?

Answer (score 3):

the thing that i can see is that you have a bad format on your json `data { payload: "{"state":{"reported":{"measuredata":{…`

it hspuld be witouth the double quote that be after the word payload `payload: "{"state"`

you have to have something like this

```
payload: {"state"
```

Comment: assuming the question does not contain a typo, this answer is the correct answer

Comment: its not "my" json. i am receiving this from Amazon AWS IoT.

Comment: do you/your company own the code/data on the server or is it a public url?

Comment: someone else of our company set up the data (values from biogas plants) to IoT. As far as i know, it automatically coverts it into JSON format.

Comment: assuming what you typed in your question is _exactly_ what you get returned (obviously its truncated in your question) then i'd ask the person who coded it to return valid json. if its a typo in the question then thats a different matter

Comment: its truncated ofc, i already asked the person and he told me that its automatically generated, he just appended the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158000/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-tipsfedora).

Answer (score 0):

**Sample code for parsing.**

```js
var data = {
    "logged_in":true,
    "town":"Dublin",
    "state":"Ohio",
    "country":"USA",
    "products":
        {
            "pic_id":"1500",
            "description":"Picture of a computer",
            "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
            "type":"jpg",
            "childrenimages":
                {
                    "pic_id":"15011",
                    "description":"Picture of a cpu",
                    "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/mycpu.png",
                    "type":"png"
                }
        }
      
};

var data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
var data_final = JSON.parse(data1);

console.log(data_final.products.pic_id);
```